# Timing animation in (Timer) game loop

Tags: c#, timer

I'm working on a small game, and I'm having trouble with some of the animations.
I want the Monsters to drop few pixels once every 3 seconds, so I added a condition for that that works. But the problem is the function that changes the Monster position, is getting called more then once, because the timer is still ticking when the condition is true.

This is the timer:

```
 gameTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
 gameTimer.Elapsed += gameTick;
 gameTimer.Interval = 10000/ 60;
 gameTimer.Enabled = true;
```

The method `gameTick`:

```
private void gameTick(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    theGame.Update(e.SignalTime.Second);
    this.Invalidate();
}
```

the Update method that I call inside the gameTick method every 3 seconds:

```
public void Update(int secondsPassed)
{
    if(secondsPassed % 3 == 0)
        monsters.Update();
}
```

How can I make sure the method `Update` gets called only ONCE every 3 seconds? 
It's like when it get to 3 seconds, the gate is opened to call the update method again until the condition turns false.

I'm not sure what can I add to the logic to stop it from running more the once.

Comment: I think the first operation in `gameTick` should be `gameTimer.Enabled = false;` then after the Update and Invalidate operations are complete you reenable the `gameTimer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your need you may want to capture current time at last update with `DateTime.Now`, add 3 seconds and call `Update` only when it passed:

```
  DateTime nextUpdateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

  private void gameTick(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
  {
     if (DateTime.UtcNow > nextUpdateTime)
     {
        nextUpdateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(3);
        theGame.Update(...);
     }
     ....
```

Note that if you are planning to debug code you should avoid direct calls to `DateTime.Now` and figure out how you want time to move while waiting on breakpoint. Check out http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/53189/322422.aspx for discussion on time in games (XNA forum).

Answer (score 0):

You should suspend the timer while `gameTick` is executing:

```
private void gameTick(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    gameTimer.Enabled = false;
    theGame.Update(e.SignalTime.Second);
    this.Invalidate();
    gameTimer.Enabled = true;
}
```